# How to identify an existing NFS or CIFS mount, is a hard or soft mount?

Tags: mount, nfs, cifs

I've two NFS shares mounted on the OS & I also have one CIFS share.
none of the above mounts in fstab file have soft or hard explicitly mentioned in their respective mount options.

So how can I find out if they are soft mounts or hard?

Comment: mountstats or nfsstats may help you with nfs mounts. Not sure about cifs right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the respective manpages. [`man mount.nfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/mount.nfs.8.html) points to [`man 5 nfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/nfs.5.html) for details, which says:

```
soft / hard   Determines the recovery behavior of the NFS client after
              an  NFS  request  times  out.   If  neither  option   is
              specified  (or  if  the  hard  option is specified), NFS
              requests are retried indefinitely.  If the  soft  option
              is  specified,  then the NFS client fails an NFS request
              after retrans retransmissions have  been  sent,  causing
              the  NFS  client  to  return  an  error  to  the calling
              application.
```

So the default unless specified otherwise for NFS is hard.

And [`man mount.cifs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html) says:

```
soft
   (default) The program accessing a file on the cifs mounted file
   system will not hang when the server crashes and will return errors
   to the user application.
```

And the default for CIFS is soft.